# opencv: extract pixels with r>b>g

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mask

I am trying to extract from an image only pixels with r>b>g with opencv in python . I don't want to use .split() because it is too slow. Can someone help me ?

I have tried things like that: (but too slow)

```
b,g,r = cv2.split(resized)

ma1 = np.logical_or(r>b,b>g)
```

**EDIT, I want to do something like this:**

```
img[img[2]>img[1] and  img[1]>img[0]]=0
```

Comment: why not [use numpy directly](https://www.degeneratestate.org/posts/2016/Oct/23/image-processing-with-numpy/#Colours) ?

Comment: I couldn't find how to compare elements from each tuple in a array without using for loops.

Comment: picture has this shape: img =[ (blue,green,red), (blue,green,red) , ... ]  and can't find in numpy documentation how to do that.

Comment: To be more clear, I want to do something like this: img[img[2]>img[1] and  img[1]>img[0]]=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this gives expected result but this works for me without error

```
img = cv2.imread(...)

img[ (img[:,:,2] > img[:,:,1]) & (img[:,:,1] > img[:,:,0]) ] = 0

cv2.imshow('image', img)
```

I don't have to split it.

Because `cv2` uses `BGR` instead of `RGB` so I had to compare in different order.

I could convert to `RGB` using

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

but then I would have to convert it back to `BGR` to display it.

---

BTW: `cv2` uses numpy array to keep `img`

```
print( type(img) )

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Ooops, I see mine is much the same as yours. I'll leave it though as it generates test data and saves the results without overwriting the original data, so is slightly different. Kudos and upvotes to you :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell example data in code is good idea to easy and fast test code. I like the use of `...` in your code which I never saw in use before.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
import numpy as np

# Generate random image
np.random.seed(42)
r = np.random.randint(0,256,(8,5,3), dtype=np.uint8) 

# Make space for results
res = np.zeros((8,5),dtype=np.uint8)

# Calculate mask
res[(r[...,0]>r[...,1]) & (r[...,1]>r[...,2])] = 1
```

Input array `r`:

```
array([[[102, 220, 225],
        [ 95, 179,  61],
        [234, 203,  92],   <--- matches
        [  3,  98, 243],
        [ 14, 149, 245]],

       [[ 46, 106, 244],
        [ 99, 187,  71],
        [212, 153, 199],
        [188, 174,  65],   <--- matches
        [153,  20,  44]],

       [[203, 152, 102],   <--- matches
        [214, 240,  39],
        [121,  24,  34],
        [114, 210,  65],
        [239,  39, 214]],

       [[244, 151,  25],
        [ 74, 145, 222],
        [ 14, 202,  85],
        [145, 117,  87],
        [184, 189, 221]],

       [[116, 237, 109],
        [ 85,  99, 172],
        [226, 153, 103],
        [235, 146,  36],
        [151,  62,  68]],

       [[181, 130, 160],
        [160, 166, 149],
        [  6,  69,   5],
        [ 52, 253, 112],
        [ 14,   1,   3]],

       [[ 76, 248,  87],
        [233, 212, 184],
        [235, 245,  26],
        [213, 157, 253],
        [ 68, 240,  37]],

       [[219,  91,  54],
        [129,   9,  51],
        [  0, 191,  20],
        [140,  46, 187],
        [147,   1, 254]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Results array:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```